# Array lost after adding all Google Maps markers

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps-api-3

For a Google Maps project I'm loading all the markers into an array so I can use it for a MarkerClusterer after putting all markers on the map. All the markers are shown but the MarkerClusterer is not clustering. After debugging I've found out that the array is empty but I can't figure out why.

```
var matLocation = null; 
var markers = [];

//setup the makers
function loadMarkers()
{
    //load array with markers
    startLoadingMarkers();

    //add markercluster to page so we markers will get clustered
    var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);
    markerCluster.maxZoom_ = 14;        

    //More stuff
}


/*
* Load the markers from the source
*/
function startLoadingMarkers()
{
    //empty markers
    for(i in markers)
    {
        var marker = markers[i];
        marker.setMap(null);
    }
    markers = [];

    $.get( 'load some marker source', function(data) { 
        matLocation = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        LoadMarker(1);
    });
}


/*
* Load the marker one by one
*/
function LoadMarker(nextIndex)
{
    if(nextIndex < matLocation.locations.length){
       var arrItem = matLocation.locations[nextIndex];

       //Put the marker on the map (all working fine)

       //add to array
       markers.push(marker);

       //go to next
       LoadMarker((nextIndex + 1));
    }
    //ARRAY IS STILL FILLED HERE
}
```

The array is filled on each iteration of the and has content at the end of all interation. But when I want to fire up the MarkerClusterer the marker array is empty and has no content.

Anyone knows what's happening here?

Comment: Could it be something related with that AJAX is asynchronous?

Answer (score 0):

On `loadMarkers` you call `startLoadingMarkers` and this does:

```
markers = [];
```

Looks like you empty the global markers before you assing to `MarkerClusterer(map, markers)`